# Has Turkey explained how their larger "safe zone" is going to be different from what's going on in Afrin?

Tags: turkey, syria, rule-of-law

Reuters [reports](https://www.apnews.com/7386b1149d2642afb3258e3d07d167dc):

> The U.N. said more than 130,000 people have fled since the Turkish [Peace Spring] operation began. As Syrian Kurdish forces fall back, there are fears that those who remain will end up like the residents of Afrin, a Kurdish enclave in northwestern Syria seized by Turkey and its Syrian allies early last year.
>
> Rights groups say the Turkish-backed fighters looted and destroyed the property of Kurdish civilians in Afrin. Last month, a U.N. commission said the overall security situation in and around Afrin ”remained dire ” as armed groups carved out their own fiefdoms. The Rojava Information Center said some factions have imposed a strict form of Islamic law.
>
> “There is a general absence of rule of law and repeated incidents of kidnappings, torture, extortion and assassination,” the U.N. commission said, adding that victims were “often of Kurdish origin as well as civilians perceived as being prosperous, including doctors, businessmen and merchants.”

Does Turkey acknowledge any of this as a problem? And if they do, have they laid out any law & order plans for the wider "safe zone" they claim along the entire border? (Note that Afrin was taken in early 2018 following [Operation Olive Branch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Olive_Branch); the news above is from this month, and the UN report on Afrin is from [September this year](https://www.ohchr.org/EN/NewsEvents/Pages/DisplayNews.aspx?NewsID=24972&LangID=E). It does not seem to differ too much in its assement of Afrin from a [report released in the summer of 2018](https://www.turkishminute.com/2018/07/09/un-report-details-human-rights-abuses-in-areas-under-turkish-military-control/).)

Comment: The objective of the invasion is to make it unsafe for Kurds, so I don't see why they'd "acknowledge" that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Wikipedia article on Operation Olive Branch makes it quite clear that the Turkish state has no tolerance for criticism. To the extent that they might acknowledge security problems do exist in Afrin, I would be surprised to find them taking any responsibility for causing this and can find no evidence that they ever have. They blame all problems in the region on "terrorists" (which they selectively define in their own interest), who they further claim to be on the forefront of defeating. They also don't pretend to care about the general security situation on the ground; their primary stated objective is to defeat the YPG.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently Turkey has denied that there are any serious problems in Afrin. [According to AFP](https://www.france24.com/en/20181012-fear-grips-syria-city-seized-kurds-turkish-backed-rebels):

> Turkey has denied allegations of abuses, and [Turkish-backed] rebels say proven offenders are punished.

And the largely state-controlled Turkish press has been [repeating the same line](http://globalcomment.com/nothing-to-see-here-the-turkish-press-and-afrin/), generally blaming any and all problems on the prior local administration in Afrin and/or [continued](https://www.voanews.com/extremism-watch/reports-turkey-backed-rebels-battle-afrin) YPG activity.